# CORS problems on node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, cors

I have a web app with a Node.js backend and Angular front end, both on the same server (Windows Server 2016), however, using different domains. So the front-end is at http://frontend.mydomain.com and the backend is at http://backend.mydomain.com.

Unfortunately I didn't write this web app, nor do I have any experience with Node.js or Angular.

The web app was working perfectly on the older server. However, we have moved both the front-end and the back-end to a new web server, and now, when trying to load it, I get this error message:

/#/login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backend.mydomain/authenticate' from origin 'http://frontend.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Now I'm looking at the server.js file in the backend folder, and this is what it looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
const sql = require("mssql");
// var cors = require("cors");

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// app.use(cors());

var config =
{
    server: "**************",
    database: "**************",
    user: "**************",
    password: "**************",
    port: 1433,
    connectionTimeout: 1500,
    requestTimeout: 1500
};

app.use(function(req, res, next)
{
    var data = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');

    req.on('data', function(chunk)
    {
       data += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function()
    {
        req.body = data;
        next();
    });
});
```

`var cors = require("cors");` and `app.use(cors());` where commented out, so I tried uncommenting it (and restarting the web service in IIS) but it made no difference.

I did some research, and tried adding things such as

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next();
}
```

as well as a myriad of other things, always remembering to restart the web service in IIS after each change, but nothing I do seems to make a difference. Any suggestions anyone please? Thanks...

**EDIT:**

So the welcome/login page loads. But as soon as I type in my username and password, and hit the Submit button, I get the error described above. Looking at Developer Tools -> Network, I see that "authenticate" is in red, and when I click on it, it shows this:

```
Request URL: http://backend.mydomain.com/authenticate
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 1208
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 10:53:26 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-AR;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 34
content-type: text/plain
Host: backend.mydomain.com
Origin: http://frontend.mydomain.com
Referer: http://frontend.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
myusername!@#$%&mypassword
```

p.s. i have changed actual domain names, usernames and passwords...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check in your browser (use the developer tools, go to Network) and ensure you're seeing requests successfully returning allowed methods, headers etc.

You should see headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If these headers are not being send back, something is going wrong with the CORS setup.

You should at the very least receive an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

It may be that something is swallowing the headers you are sending back (such as a proxy). In this case the calls will fail.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I'm not seeing those replies... but i'm not sure if i'm looking in the right place. So in Chrome, I opened Developer Tools and then went to the Network tab as you described. I don't see anything that even starts with Access-Control-Allow anywhere...

Comment: Hey @FabricioRodriguez, as long as you are seeing the server headers, like HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 53
ETag: W/"35-ZrfXQKBFPK8mxe6OrgGdsTE1blI"
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 10:23:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive.   Now, the Cors headers will look like Access-Control-Allow-x.

Comment: Thanks Terry. It looks like it's failing on authenticate. I have edited my original post to show exactly what it says (at the bottom of the post)

Comment: What's really strange is that your Server header is showing Microsoft-IIS/10.0. Normally this should be Express if this is served by a Node.js script. Are you sure this script is being run on the server at all?

Comment: Alas I'm not sure... I'm not too clued up on this :( when I moved the two web apps (front-end and back-end) from the old server to the new server, I simply copied the files across from the old C:\inetpub to the new c:\inetpub, then I created Websites in IIS and set up the IP bindings. That's all. I did the same thing for some other PHP web apps that I had to move across and that worked fine. But this Angluar/Node.js web app is unfortunately giving me these CORS headcahes

Comment: ok i just noted that on IIS, if i right-click on the backend website, and click "Manage Website" -> "Advanced Properties", on the old server, "Application Pool" is set to "node" whereas on the new server, it is set to "legalworxServer" (which is the name of the server web app)

Comment: I would suggest setting the Application Pool to node, that's more likely the setting you require!

Comment: I tried to change "Application Pool" to "node" on the new server, but I don't have that option... I think you're right... perhaps Node.js is not properly set up on the server

Comment: You know what, i'm embarrased to say this, but I think I didn't install node js on the new server... :/

Comment: :-) we've all been there, I'd install node and see where you are from there!

Comment: I'm installing it now... will let you know if that does the trick. Thanks for your support Terry... I don't know, maybe it's the whole working from home thing lol (we're currently in Coronavirus lockdown here in South Africa)

Comment: Oh yes, I hear you mate, we're in lockdown in Ireland too.... strange times. Stay safe!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Terry. Yes, I was indeed missing some components - thanks to your help I figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen sometimes when the origin didn't implemented correctly, you can setup the back-end for this situation:

Use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm (in nodejs back-end) for setup the allowed origin by yourself:

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({
  origin: //Hardcoded string of your coming request path or regex for filter anything,
  //Like this: "http://frontend.mydomain.com" or /frontend.mydomain.com/
  credentials: true //Allow the server to get cookies and other auth data from other 
  // domains and ports to send cookies
}));
```

This is worked for me but in some cases you may get in trouble with preflight requests which are some kind of issue that the origin (a path which request is coming from) is not implemented correctly, You have to set a Express middleware for set some header manually (Like yourself):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://frontend.mydomain.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  next();
});
```

You have to put this all together like this:

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://frontend.mydomain.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  next();
});

app.use(cors({
  origin: //Hardcoded string of your coming request path or regex for check in string,
  //Like this: "http://frontend.mydomain.com" or /frontend.mydomain.com/
  credentials: true //Allow the server to get cookies and other auth data from other 
  // domains and ports
}));
```

In `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://frontend.mydomain.com")` it's better that you put a specific domain for the origin instead of a `"*"` because it may be not secure at all. When you put `"*"` CORS policy would prevent the credentials to be passed.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the allowed http methods in your app.use()-

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next();
}
```